# Помогите вспомнить, в какой книге был пример "Подбрасывания монеты по телефону"

Tags: криптография, шифрование

Всё, что помню, это Алиса и Боб подбрасывали монету по телефону, и в этом примере ни Боб, ни Алиса не могли выбрать такой вариант, который был бы выгоден кому-либо. В общем, если Алиса подбросила монету, и сказала Бобу, что выпала решка, хотя выпал орел, Боб смог бы доказать то, что Алиса его обманула.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Прикладная криптография" Шнайдера

Даже вопрос был на эту тему: [Использование RSA для "Ментального покера"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742633/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-rsa-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0/742794#742794)

Comment: Да, это она. Спасибо большое.